# How to disable browser popup/tooltip when user exceeds max in a number input?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

How can I disable the tooltip in the image that happens when a user manually enters a quantity over the max?

The tooltip is showing when the user tries to submit the form, and I need to disable it.  I'm pretty sure this is generated by the browser, not any of the libraries I am using.  If someone can confirm that, it would be appreciated.

[image]

I am using material UI with React Hook Form:

```
<Controller
    name={`quantity${sku}`}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={currentQuantity}
    render={({ onChange, onBlur }) => (
        <OutlinedInput
            defaultValue={currentQuantity}
            type="number"
            name={`quantity${sku}`}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={e => {
                handleChange(e);
                onChange(e);
            }}
            onBlur={e => {
                handleChange(e);
                onBlur(e);
            }}
            inputProps={{
                maxLength: 2,
                max: maxQuantity || 99,
                min: 1
            }}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `noValidate` attribute will prevent the validation

```
 <form noValidate>
    <input type="number" max="10" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```